# How to populate nested dynamic form field with the data for selected value of the drop down on Update form in Yii 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am  using dynamic form widget in Yii 2 for implementing nested dynamic form. I have a form which allows the user to select ASC center and add students data for each time. The scenario is a user selects ASC center from the drop down list. Upon selecting the ASC center, a function called StudentList returns the students for the selected ASC center. Now these students are populating correctly.

I have assigned a class for the Student input field and used each function of the jquery to populate all the students field with the data returned by the StudentList function. This is working correctly for create action

But on the update it causes issue like all students are displayed for loaded fields. As shown in the image, it is the update page and student data is loaded but when the user clicks on the drop down of loaded student data then all students are displayed.

Below is the function StudentList which returns the list of students for specific ASC center.

```
public function actionStudentLists($id)
    {
        $countstudents = Student::find()->where(['ASCId' => $id])->count();//Counts number of students

        $Students = Student::find()->where(['ASCId' => $id])->all(); // Execute students for ASCId

        if ($countstudents > 0) {

        echo "<option value>Select Students</option>";  

            foreach ($Students as $Student) {
        ob_start();

             echo "<option value='" . $Student->StudentId . "'>" . $Student->StudentName . "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option> - </option>";
        }
    }
```

Below is the _form.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;

use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use app\models\Ascassignment;
use app\models\Asccenter;
use kartik\time\TimePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Student;
?>

<script>
$(function () {

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});

$("#dynamic-form")[0].reset();

});

// When the user clicks on Add Student button
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".dynamicform_student").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    const $i = $(item).find('.i');

    $.post("index.php?r=student/student-lists&id="+$("select#ascteacherreport-ascid").val(),function(data){
 $i.html(data);
        });

    });
});


//When the user clicks on Add Time button
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
        const $i = $(item).find('.i');

       $.post("index.php?r=student/student-lists&id="+$("select#ascteacherreport-ascid").val(),function(data){

     $i.html(data);

});
// When the user clicks on Add Student button
$(".dynamicform_student").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    const $i = $(item).find('.i');

    $.post("index.php?r=student/student-lists&id="+$("select#ascteacherreport-ascid").val(),function(data){
 $i.html(data);
        });

    });
    });
});
</script>



<div class="ascteacherreport-form">

   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form',  'options' => ['class' => 'disable-submit-buttons'],
   ]);?>

   <div class="panel panel-primary " >
<div class="panel panel-heading"><font size="3"><b>Teacher Report</b></font></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ASCId')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Asccenter::find()->leftJoin('ascassignment','`ascassignment`.`ASCId`=`asccenter`.`ASCId`')->where(['ascassignment.UserId' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->getonlyid()])->all(),'ASCId','ASCName'), ['prompt' => 'Select ASC Center','class'=>'form-control ascid','onChange' => '

    $.post("index.php?r=student/student-lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(),function(data){

         $(".i").each(function(k,v)
        {
            $(".i").html(data);

        }
        );

    });
    '
    ]) ?>
    </div>

<div class="col-sm-4">

    <?= $form->field($model, 'DateofReport')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        //'language' => 'ru',
    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],                                              'clientOptions'=>['changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'readOnly'=>true]

]) ?>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>



<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><font size="3"><b>Time and Student Details</b></font></div>
<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
        'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',
        'widgetBody' => '.container-items',
        'widgetItem' => '.time-item',
        'limit' =>10,
        'min' => 1,
        'insertButton' => '.add-time',
        'deleteButton' => '.remove-time',
        'model' => $modelsTime[0],
        'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
        'formFields' => [
            'FromTime',
            'ToTime'
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor='#B8B8B8'>
            <th style='border: 1px solid black;'></th>
               <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Time</th>
                <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Student Details</th>
                <th class="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <button type="button" class="add-time btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Time</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="container-items">
        <?php foreach ($modelsTime as $indexTime => $modelTime): ?>
            <tr class="time-item">
                <td class="vcenter" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <?php
                        // necessary for update action.
                        if (! $modelTime->isNewRecord) {
                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelTime, "[{$indexTime}]ASCReportDetailsId");
                        }
                    ?>
                    </td>
                    <td style='border: 1px solid black;width:15%'>


                    <?=  $form->field($modelTime, "[{$indexTime}]FromTime")->label(true)->widget(TimePicker::classname(),[

    'pluginOptions' => [
        'readOnly' => true,
        'minuteStep' => 1,
    ],
])?><br>

                <?=
                    $form->field($modelTime, "[{$indexTime}]ToTime")->label(true)->widget(TimePicker::classname(),[

    'pluginOptions' => [
        'readOnly' => true,
        'minuteStep' => 1,
    ],
])?>



                </td>

                <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <?= $this->render('_form-studentdata', [
                        'form' => $form,
                        'indexTime' => $indexTime,
                        'modelsStudentdata' => $modelsStudentdata[$indexTime],
                    ]) ?>


                </td>

                <td class="text-center vcenter" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                    <button type="button" class="remove-time btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>

</div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Below is the nested form _form-studentdata.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
//use nex\datepicker\DatePicker;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use app\models\Student;
?>


<?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_student',
    'widgetBody' => '.container-student',
    'widgetItem' => '.student-item',
    'limit' => 50,
    'min' => 1,
    'insertButton' => '.add-student',
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-student',
    'model' => $modelsStudentdata[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'StudentId',
        'Subject',

        'Topic',
        'Confidence',
    ],
]); ?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor='#B8B8B8'>
            <th style='border: 1px solid black;'></th>
                <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Student</th>
                <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Subject</th>
                <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Topic</th>
                                <th class ="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>Confidence</th>


            <th class="text-center" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                <button type="button" class="add-student btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Student</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="container-student">
    <?php foreach ($modelsStudentdata as $indexStudent => $modelStudentdata): ?>
        <tr class="student-item">
            <td class="vcenter" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
                <?php
                    // necessary for update action.
                    if (! $modelStudentdata->isNewRecord) {
                        echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelStudentdata, "[{$indexTime}][{$indexStudent}]ASCTeacherReportTimeDetailsId");
                    }
                ?>
                </td>
                <td style='border: 1px solid black; width:30%'>
                <?= $form->field($modelStudentdata, "[{$indexTime}][{$indexStudent}]StudentId")->label(false)->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Student::find()->all(),'StudentId','StudentName'), ['prompt' => 'Select Student','class'=>'form-control i']) ?>
            </td>
            <td style='border: 1px solid black; width:30%'>
                <?= $form->field($modelStudentdata, "[{$indexTime}][{$indexStudent}]Subject")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </td>
            <td style='border: 1px solid black; width:30%'>
                <?= $form->field($modelStudentdata, "[{$indexTime}][{$indexStudent}]Topic")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </td>

            <td style='border: 1px solid black; width:30%'>
                <?= $form->field($modelStudentdata, "[{$indexTime}][{$indexStudent}]Confidence")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center vcenter" style=" border: 1px solid black;width: 90px;">
                <button type="button" class="remove-student btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
```

Current Image : Image shows the update form where data is loaded from the database but when clicked on drop down of the student field then all the students are displayed. Only selected ASC Center's students should be displayed in the loaded Student field.

[Update Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI2RO.png)

Comment: Are you sure all the students in your database do not have an Id of 'ASCId'?  Also does the $students / $student variable exist anywhere else in your code that could be conflicting?

Comment: Yes there are other students who have different ASCId. These are also getting displayed in the drop down which should not, only selected ASC center students should be populated.

Comment: Does the $students / $student variable used in your foreach exist anywhere else in your code that could be conflicting?

Comment: I have posted the nested form code above. I don't seem that the variable $students or $student is conflicting the code

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the data in your database table has records without a value in the ASCId column.  If the condition 'ASCId' => $id is met the records in the Student table that have an empty or NULL value for the ASCId column, would still be included in the result.

Verify that the Student model in your Yii 2 application has the ASCId column defined as a property, and it is properly mapped to the corresponding column in the database.  Yii 2 may not recognize it as a valid column and may not include it in the generated SQL queries.

Double-check the spelling and case sensitivity of the column name 'ASCId' in both the database table and the Yii 2 model to ensure they match.

Comment: No null or empty values for ASCId column in the student table and asccenter table. There are 4  ascccenters in the asccenter table with the id 6,7,8,9 and there are students in the student table for asccenter 6,7, and 9. No null values for ASCId column. Student model has ASCId field and is correctly mapped. ASCId column name spelling and case sensitivity are correct..